# Mysql Query taking long time to execute

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, cordova

I have made a sql query from wordpress backened

Below is my query

```
SELECT distinct p.id, p.post_title,s.new_price
FROM wp_mostviewd as v ,wp_store_price_update as s ,wp_posts as p where v.pro_count=(select max(pro_count) from wp_mostviewd as v where p.id=v.pro_id) and post_status='publish'  and s.new_price = (select min(new_price) from wp_store_price_update as s where p.id= s.product_id) group by v.pro_count desc
```

Above query taking more time to execute. After taking so much time this query giving me below result

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1858 [title] => Fifa 15 [price] => 300 [image] => http://s33rnet.ipage.com/dev/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/download-ثبث-214x226.jpg ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 1396 [title] => Galaxy S5 [price] => 1799 [image] => http://s33rnet.ipage.com/dev/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/samsung_galaxy_s53-200x226.jpg ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 1414 [title] => iphone 6 plus 128GB [price] => 3999 [image] => http://s33rnet.ipage.com/dev/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/iphone6-plus-specs-hero-2014.png ) )
```

But It's taking so much time even my localhost stop responding due to this query. So please short this query as i have to use this url in my phonegap web app.

Above array will be converted into json but its not responding only showing loader and this json url will be used in phonegap app using ajax.

acctually i want to fetch product details from store update table and most viewed table

creating json for most viewed products..

new prices i'm fetching from store update table where i have used select query for choosing minimum prices from the new_price column for each product and it's gives me 36 results

now for most viewed product i have fetched pro_count from most_viewd table by using product id..andselect is being used for product counts

please check it..as i need short query for this

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Show us the structure of the tables referenced in that query, together with details of any indexes on those tables; and the result of doing an EXPLAIN on the query

Comment: 1. What is the pourpose of the query? 2. Avoid implicit joins and favor explicit ones, implicit join is "deprecated" and left for compatility with old systems and with explicit join you can separate joins and filters predicates

Answer (score 3):

My First guess would be there is no indexing set up on you're table(s).

Try doing an EXPLAIN on you're query, this will show what part(s) are slow and/or badly indexed.

Comment: ohk sure i 'l eaplain my query